# match prices using JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get prices from a site and find the cheapest one by matching them.

I wrote a script that will click the buttons so I`ll see all the prices and pick them. What should I do next?

Here`s my code:

```
var rooms = document.querySelectorAll(" .btn-a-offers");
console.log(rooms);
for (var room=0;room<rooms.length;room++){
  rooms[room].click();
}
var prices = document.querySelectorAll(" .li-right-side>strong");
console.log(price);
for(var price=0; price<price.length;price++){

}
```

Also I need to get only price, without currency symbol

[image]

how is it possible to get price out from that tag?

[image]

Comment: you have get all price (or is there an error?) but what you want to solve? maybe use `String.substr` to remove the symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try innerHTML or innerText:

```
document.querySelector("#offer2 .pri_room_rates strong").innerHTML
```

```js
var prices = [];
document.querySelectorAll(".pri_room_rates strong").forEach(function(price) {
  prices.push(parseFloat(price.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,"")))
})
console.log(
  Math.min(...prices).toFixed(2) // the lowest found
)
```

```html
<div id="offer1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="pri_room_rates">
        <div></div>
        <div><strong>£200.00</strong></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
<div id="offer2">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="pri_room_rates">
        <div></div>
        <div><strong>£300.00</strong></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
  
  <div id="offer3">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="pri_room_rates">
        <div></div>
        <div><strong>£100.00</strong></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
```

Comment: Ok, now i got the price returned, but it`s not the lowest price, but the highest, how do I match them?

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it returns the price that doesn`t exist - 225.00 but the lowest price is 450

Comment: Impossible for me to test since you have not provided a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

use innerText of the Elements :

```
var prices = document.querySelectorAll(" .li-right-side>strong");
console.log(price);
for(var price=0; price<price.length;price++){
     console.log(prices[price].innerText);
}
```